# Cosmos DB Change Feed in two collections

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I would like how to face this scenario in Cosmos DB:

- I have a Collection A with a change feed which updates values in a Collection B.
- I have the Collection B with a change feed which updates values in Collection A.

This scenario creates a infinite loop.

Is there a specific way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Is the change that happens on the second step identifiable? Is it adding a particular property? Can you add more details on that?

Comment: Not, it is not identifiable and it is not adding a particular property. Basically, the item in the collection B is embebbed in many items in the collection A. The case here is that the changes in an item in the collection B must update the embebbed references in the collection A, so far so good. The issue is that an updated item in the Collection A must update the properties of the item in the Collection B based on its embebbed item.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the proposed design fundamentally violates the principles of the [event sourcing pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing). As discussed in the linked overview, an important property of the architecture is that updates are idempotent, i.e. that there is no side effect of multiple equivalent operations. In the described case, this would mean that attempts to update an item or embedded item with the same value would be detected and prevented, to avoid a loop.

In general, there should be a "source of truth" with one-way movement of data. I would avoid two-way change feed architectures altogether. If you are trying to optimize reads by embedding a copy of another item, the copy should be read-only and not subject to updates that flow in the reverse direction. Only the original should be writable.

Comment: Do you mean that the copy should only support write and delete so that it can be used as  read-only and can't be updated?

Comment: In effect, yes. That would have to be enforced in code, not possible at the Cosmos level as far as I know.